# cannot open input file 'Delayimp.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, delay-load

I am compiling a project under Visual Studio 2013 (OS: Windows 7). The Project is compiled with the Platform Toolset "Visual Studio 2008 (v90)". In the options I have set a dll to be loaded delayed like this:

> /DELAYLOAD:"PluginPost.dlll"

The error I am getting is the following:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Delayimp.lib'

And now my question is the following. I know that I need the Delayimp.lib in order to load a dll delayed, but where do I find this Delayimp.lib?

Thank you in advance for any hints.

PS. I am compiling a 64 Bit application.

Comment: It is supposed to be present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64.  It is on any healthy install of VS2013.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2017 Community, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x64\delayimp.lib`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add `;C:\Windows\System32` to your PATH system variable at `Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables`. Also pay attention to not use unnecessary spaces between each path.

In Reference to:

https://rocket1.unrealengine.cloud.answerhub.com/questions/74685/ue431-preview-hot-recompile-cant-find-delayimplib.html

Comment: that did not help, i already have sys32 in the path, but adding to the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64` did help, i was able to build Release, x64 and it made AppInstallerCLI.exe