# Node-java : Install error: "fatal error LNK1181 cannot open input file DelayImp.lib"

Tags: java, node.js, visual-studio-2017, node-java

I'm trying to install java on my node server but I'm facing some problems.

My computer :

- Windows 10 x64
- Node v7.9.0
- NPM v5.8.0-next.0
- Visual Studio 2017

From Visual Studio Installer, C++ modules :

- SDK Windows 10
- SDK Windows 8.1
- SDK UCRT

From Path :

- JDK 1.8.0_131
- JRE 9.0.4
- MSBuild 14.0
- Full path to CL.exe from Visual Studio 2017 install

Error I got when I'm using "npm install java" :

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'DelayImp.lib'

I can't figure out what's wrong :(

I saw this question but it didn't help me: [cannot open input file 'Delayimp.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410604/cannot-open-input-file-delayimp-lib)

I opened a Github issue too, where you can find the full error log file : https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/424

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of things to fix it, probably ugly but it's working now :

- Installed Node v8.9.1
- I copied the file needed from my VS2017 installation (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\lib\x64) to Windows Kits installation (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64)
- Updating VS2017/2015 C++ Build tools from VS installer
- Added VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140
- Added GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015

Hope this help